# "exp_internal 1" output doesn't seem to match telnet output

Tags: expect

**Quick background:** I'm running a training datacenter & we automated the switch factory-default reset via PowerScript that calls upon Expect scripts. This is my first time posting in SOF so pardon me if I'm posting way too much info.

**Question (1)**
Is there any way to improve the readability of "exp_internal 1" output? It seems pretty messy with real output (info displayed in telnet terminal) & diagnostic output jumbled up together.

**Question (2)**
Not sure if this is a readability issue but the diagnostic output below doesn't match the telnet output.

**My expect script:**

```
#!/bin/expect
exp_internal 1
# Set variables passed on by previous script
set acsip [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
set name [lindex $argv 2]
set station [lindex $argv 3]
set timeout 240

# Connect to ACS and prepare N1234 switch for the beginning of class
send_user "\n\n"
send_user "==================================================================================\n"
send_user " Preparing switch $name in station $station for the beginning of class...         \n"
send_user "==================================================================================\n"
send_user "\n\n"
spawn telnet $acsip $port
expect *
send "\r"
expect {
    ">" {#code_snipped}
    "(config)#" {
        send "\r"
        expect {
            "Use ? to list commands." {send "end\r"}
            "% Unrecognized command" {send "end\r"}
            "(config)#" {send "end\r"}
        }
        expect "#"
        send "\r"
    }
    "#" {#code_snipped}
    "More-- or (q)uit" {#code_snipped}
}
expect "#"
send "delete startup-config\r"
```

**exp_internal 1 output (full version to show the mess as questioned in (1) above):**

```
Your group is currently "mkpasswd".  This indicates that your
gid is not in /etc/group and your uid is not in /etc/passwd.

The /etc/passwd (and possibly /etc/group) files should be rebuilt.
See the man pages for mkpasswd and mkgroup then, for example, run

mkpasswd -l [-d] > /etc/passwd
mkgroup  -l [-d] > /etc/group

Note that the -d switch is necessary for domain users.


==================================================================================
 Preparing switch N1234-2 in station 1 for the beginning of class...
==================================================================================


spawn telnet 192.168.1.1 3004
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {3008}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
send: sending "\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
"(config)#"? no
"#"? no
"More-- or (q)uit"? no

expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\n\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nTrying 192.168.
1.1..." (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern
">"? no
"(config)#"? Connected to 192.168.1.1.no
"#"? Escape character is '^]'.no
"More-- or (q)uit"? no

expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\n\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r" (spawn_id e
xp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
"(config)#"? no
"#"? no
"More-- or (q)uit"? no

expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\n\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\r       " (s
pawn_id exp4) match glob pattern
">"? no
"(config)#"? no
"#"? no
"More-- or (q)uit"? no

expect: does "                  Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\n\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\
r\n\r\r                  \rvrrp                     Dis
" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
"(config)#"? no
"#"? no
"More-- or (q)uit"? no

expect: does "vrrp                     Display virtual router redundancy protocol status.Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\n\r\n
Connected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\r                  \rvrrp                     Display vir
tual router redundancy protocol status.\r\r\n\r\r\ncon" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern
">"?
no
"(config)#"? no
"#"? no
"More-- or (q)uit"? no

expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\n\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\r
       \rvrrp                     Display virtual router redundancy protocol status.\r\r\n\r\r\nconsole(config)#do show
" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
"(config)#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "(config)#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying 192.168.1.1...\r\n\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.1.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\
r\n\r\r                  \rvrrp                     Display virtual router redundancy protocol status.\r\r\n\r\r\nconsol
e(config)#"
send: sending "\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "do show " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "Use ? to list commands."? no
"% Unrecognized command"? no
"(config)#"? no

expect: does "console(config)#do show do show \r\r\n\r\r\n% " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern
"Use ? to list commands."?
no
"% Unrecognized command"? no
"(config)#"? no

expect: does "% Unrecognized commanddo show \r\r\n\r\r\n% Unrecognized command\r\r\nc" (spawn_id exp4) match glob patter
n
"Use ? to list commands."?
no
"% Unrecognized command"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "% Unrecognized command"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "do show \r\r\n\r\r\n% Unrecognized command"
send: sending "end\r" to { exp4 }
expect: does "\r\r\nc" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "#"? no
expect: does "\r\r\nconsole(config)#" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\r\nconsole(config)#"
send: sending "\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "#"? no

expect: does "e" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "#"? no

console(config)#endexpect: does "end\r\r\nconso
" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "
#"? no

expect: does "end\r\r\nconsole#\r\r\nconsole#console#" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern
"#"?
yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "end\r\r\nconsole#"
send: sending "delete startup-config\r" to { exp4 }
```

**exp_internal 1 output (the non-matching part):**

The below diagnostic shows that after *"end\r"* is sent, expect is looking for *"#"*. *"#"* is found by matching *"\r\r\nconsole(config)#"*. Subsequently *"\r"* is sent.

```
send: sending "end\r" to { exp4 }
expect: does "\r\r\nc" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "#"? no
expect: does "\r\r\nconsole(config)#" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\r\nconsole(config)#"
send: sending "\r" to { exp4 }
```

**Telnet output:**

Output below doesn't match the diagnostic above. After *"end\r"* is sent, the next "#" found is actually *"console#"*, not *"console(config)#"*. This is evident by the fact that the next *"\r"* is sent on the *"console#"* prompt as well, not *"console(config)#"* as displayed in the diagnostic output above..

```
Your group is currently "mkpasswd".  This indicates that your
gid is not in /etc/group and your uid is not in /etc/passwd.

The /etc/passwd (and possibly /etc/group) files should be rebuilt.
See the man pages for mkpasswd and mkgroup then, for example, run

mkpasswd -l [-d] > /etc/passwd
mkgroup  -l [-d] > /etc/group

Note that the -d switch is necessary for domain users.


==================================================================================
 Preparing switch N3024-2 in station 1 for the beginning of class...         
==================================================================================


spawn telnet 10.206.196.69 3004
Trying 10.206.196.69...

Connected to 10.206.196.69.
Escape character is '^]'.



vrrp                     Display virtual router redundancy protocol status.



console(config)#do show 



% Unrecognized command

console(config)#end

console#

console#delete startup-config
```

So am I reading the diagnostic info right or is there some other method to go about it to ensure accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer, an extended comment)

Yes, the diagnostic output is messy. I don't see how to get around that: you have to be shown what input expect sees, and how it does or doesn't match your patterns.

I don't understand how "do show" appears after you hit enter. Is this expected behaviour?

I also don't understand why you hit enter right after spawning the telnet command. Is that required?

Yes, after you see `(config)#` and send `end\r`, that expect command ends and the next command expects "#"

```
    expect {
        "Use ? to list commands." {send "end\r"}
        "% Unrecognized command" {send "end\r"}
        "(config)#" {send "end\r"}
    }
    expect "#"
    send "\r"
```

I'd recommend you try to get out of nesting expect statements. It makes the logic very hard to follow. Learn about the `exp_continue` command.

Comment: The switches that my expect script telnets to are usually half-configured by students. Therefore, it needs to be able to handle all possible scenarios, e.g. students could have left it at user EXEC or global config mode. The `do show` appeared because I was running the scenario where students left the switch at `console(config)# do show ?` command. When the expect script telnets to the switch & sends `\r`, it causes the switch to quit the help mode & returns `console(config)# do show`

Comment: Unlike a typical console, the switch doesn't prompt user for credential upon connection. Therefore, I wrote the expect script to send `\r` upon spawning or else there's nothing to expect but timeout.

Comment: About the part that I mentioned as mismatch, I understand that the script & the telnet output are correct but my point is, the diagnostic output seems to be misleading. After it sends `end\r`, it's supposed to expect `config#` (I code it as `expect "#"`) before sending `\r`. However, the diagnostic output says that the matching part is `\r\r\nconsole(config)#` instead of `config#` which got me confused.